# Как проанализировать массив полученных сообщений ВК?

Tags: php, массивы, json

Как проанализировать следующий массив (массив >> object >> `fwd_messages` — аж до последнего элемента):

```
{
  "type": "message_new",
  "object": {
    "id": 40,
    "date": 1465562141,
    "out": 0,
    "user_id": 0,
    "read_state": 0,
    "title": " ... ",
    "body": "",
    "fwd_messages": [{
      "user_id": 1,
      "date": 1465562135,
      "body": "",
      "fwd_messages": [{
        "user_id": 1,
        "date": 1465562132,
        "body": "",
        "fwd_messages": [{
          "user_id": 1,
          "date": 1465562129,
          "body": "",
          "fwd_messages": [{
            "user_id": 1,
            "date": 1465562126,
            "body": "",
            "fwd_messages": [{
              "user_id": 1,
              "date": 1465562123,
              "body": "1"
            }]
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  },
  "group_id": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну смотря что конкретно нужно получить. Например можно через функцию с рекурсией. Данный пример выводить все значения date из fwd_messages.

```
$json = '{"type":"message_new","object":{"id":40,"date":1465562141,"out":0,"user_id":0,"read_state":0,"title":" ... ","body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1465562135,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1465562132,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1465562129,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1465562126,"body":"","fwd_messages":[{"user_id":1,"date":1465562123,"body":"1"}]}]}]}]}]},"group_id":0}';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

function getFwd_messages($arr) {
    if (isset($arr['object']['fwd_messages'])) {
        getFwd_messages($arr['object']['fwd_messages'][0]);
    }
    elseif (isset($arr['user_id'])){
        echo ('date >> ' . $arr['date']) . '<br>';
        if(isset($arr['fwd_messages'])) {
            getFwd_messages($arr['fwd_messages'][0]);
        }
    }
}

getFwd_messages($arr);

// date >> 1465562135
// date >> 1465562132
// date >> 1465562129
// date >> 1465562126
// date >> 1465562123
```

Comment: зачем такие сложности когда это решаеться просто проходом в `foreach()`.

Comment: Я только за, тоже хочу увидеть более простое и правильное решение, пришлите ваш вариант, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Naumov какими сложностями? Тут просто рекурсия. У тебя в конечном итоге получится тоже самое, максимум немного короче